# What are the pixel dimensions for launch images?

Tags: ios

Been through Apple's documentation & ended up more confused that before.

I've got five spaces for iPhone portrait launch image in Xcode.

for iOS 5&6 1 ~ 320x480  2 ~ 640 x 960, of course.

Then how do I populate Retina 4 for iOS 5/6?

Then 7/8 2x & retina 4?

I've fill in the blank on two points, but I'm missing guidance on the remaining three.

I can intuit most of this, but without a clear instruction, I'm concerned I'll go off-track without the specs.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Use image assets for the launch images and Xcode will show you the size for each launch image.

Comment: @Thelaws.  That's the document that isn't helpful.

Comment: @Maddy I'm looking at image assets and Xcode is not showing me any sizes.  Can you please specify how to get the sizes to display?

Comment: Select a specific launch image in the asset then bring up the Utilities pane on the right side of Xcode. Click on the fat down-arrow icon at the top of the Utility pane.

Comment: Got it.  There are three different sizes, but five spaces to populate, with the expected size in the Attributes Inspector.